# How do I change the boot menu when I have no display?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I normally have my boot menu set to skip the boot options and go directly into Windows 10. Today I decided to run some Seagate Tools from an ISO. So I used EasyBCD to add an option to my boot menu to boot into the ISO, and I set it as default. I forgot to change my menu to not skip the boot menu. How do I get out of this "only boot into the ISO" option I have set for myself?

I should note that my monitor, an ASUS MG279, is plugged in via DisplayPort to my Dell Precision T7500. The monitor goes to sleep when the boot menu is shown. This is why I normally skip the menu and go straight into Windows. As such, I don't know what is being shown on my screen and I don't know how to get back into Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: When the PC is booting, keep pressing F8. This will make the boot menu show up. Then try to move around and press enter. If your bios menu shows up with F8, it can be a problem.

Option 2: Boot from CD (will work only if default) and repair your OS. If it is not default, you have a chance if your HDD is hot plugable. Just remove the HDD and boot from CD, then quickly plug in the drive as soon as something shows up on the display.

Option 3: Try the same thing above using a live Linux CD. Since this is a full OS, it should have less issues with hot plugging.

Option 4: Try a different monitor.

Option 5: Connect HDD to another PC and repair from there.

Comment: @Nathan, can you please mention which option worked if it did, for the benefit of others.